# How to redirect www to non-www while keeping URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I try to redirect all requests on any URI with a www to the same URL without www. So

- http://www.domain.com -> http://domain.com
- http://www.domain.com/some/page -> http://domain.com/some/page
- http://www.domain.com/some/page.html?p=x -> http://domain.com/some/page.html?p=x

The rules I'm using at the moment are

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

But it only seems to work on the main domain, not on subpages.

Also important: Other subdomains like static.domain.com should still work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule with `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: There was no intent to make `www` optional since question was on redirect from `www` to `non www`

Comment: That does not work. It only redirects the main domain. Not the subpages.

Comment: Do you have other rules also in this .htaccess? Make sure this is very first rule and there is no other .htaccess any where

Comment: That last comment did the trick. I had other rewrite rules above it. Thanks!

Comment: Add %{ENV:protossl} after http on the rule. If not, SSL acces won't be redirected.

Comment: Yes if `https` is a possibility then `RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` is good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```